# Is it better to set_index in Pandas then convert to Dask or vice versa?

Tags: pandas, dask

The Dask documentation states that Dask's set_index is much more expensive than Pandas' (http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.set_index)

With that in mind, which of the following should be a best practice (the 'time' column is filled with datetime objects).

set_index in Dask:

```
        df['time_index'] = df['time']
        df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)
        df = df.set_index('time_index', sorted=True)
```

set_index in Pandas

```
        df['time_index'] = df['time']
        df = df.set_index('time_index')
        df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)
```

I welcome any recommendations to improve my example code as well.

Comment: Do you mind to provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: In particular if you are able to tell us which one is your error it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks, @rpanai.  I removed the question about the error.  I'm more focused on what is the best practice here.  If I encounter the error again, I'll post that separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm wondering why you need a to duplicate the `time` column to `time_index` anyway here is an example

## Create df

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd


N =  int(1e7)
times = pd.date_range(start="2019-01-01", periods=N, freq="1s")
df = pd.DataFrame({"time":times,
                   "value":np.random.randn(N)})

df.to_csv("df.csv", index=False)
df.to_parquet("df.parq")
```

## Set index in pandas

```py
%%time
df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", parse_dates=['time'])
df = df.set_index("time")
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)

a = df.divisions

CPU times: user 10.7 s, sys: 503 ms, total: 11.2 s
Wall time: 9.81 s
```

## Set index in dask

```py
time
df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", parse_dates=['time'])
df = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=100)
df = df.set_index("time", sorted=True)
b = df.divisions

CPU times: user 11.3 s, sys: 534 ms, total: 11.8 s
Wall time: 10.4 s
```

The divisions is the same

```py
print(a==b)

True
```

## Read with dask

Here we can use infer_division and use `time` as index as long as we are reading from `parquet`.

```py
%%time
df = dd.read_parquet("df.parq", index="time", infer_divisions=True)
df = df.repartition(npartitions=100)
c = df.divisions

CPU times: user 9.54 ms, sys: 22 µs, total: 9.56 ms
Wall time: 8.9 ms
```

In this case the division is not the same

```py
print(c==a)

False
```

But it shouldn't be a big deal

```py
print(c[:2])

(Timestamp('2019-01-01 00:00:00'),
Timestamp('2019-01-02 03:46:39.990000128'))
```

## Conclusions

I'd suggest you to read directly with dask from parquet. Your file is going to be smaller and you don't have to specify the datatypes

```sh
!ls -lh df.*

-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 378M Jun  5 14:59 df.csv
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 164M Jun  5 14:59 df.parq
```

Comment: Thank you for all of this.  Amazing speed gains on the read_parquet and I wasn't aware of the infer_divisions option.  RE: copying the time into a time_index column - please correct me if I'm wrong, but it seemed that when you set a column as an index, you lose that column as a standalone column.  I want to maintain the time column for other reasons.

Comment: @dan you can still access to the column as it's not going anywhere. The only difference is that you need to call it as `df.index` instead of `df["time"]` as example if you want to create a new columns with weekday you can just do  `df["weekday"] = df.index.dt.weekday`

Comment: Thank you again.  Just upvoted now (my reputation was too low to upvote until this morning).  Yes, the .index requirement is what I was worried about.  I would have to rewrite some older analytics code to account for that.  Easier for me to create a duplicate time column for now, even if I take a performance hit (which appears rather small in the scheme of things).